# Any manuals on the development of "sympathetic joy" and or "gladness" apart from Visuddhimagga?

Tags: meditation, enjoyment, joy

As titled. I wonder if there are other methods of development outlined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There're quite a lot of essays on the Brahmavihara written by Vens. Thanissaro, Buddharakkhita, Siriwardhana, Nanamoli, etc. and of course in the Nikaya suttas themselves. See various links [here](https://accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html#metta) and [here](https://accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html#karuna)